# Issue with creating RSS Feed in Django

Tags: django, rss

I have to create a web app which shows events related to servers for an upcoming interview.  I have to include an RSS Feed of all the events related to the server.  I have decided to implement this in Django.

I have followed the Django tutorial on creating a Feed and looked at the tutorial points tutorial but I am coming up the the following error.

DoesNotExist at /server_status/latest/feed/
Event matching query does not exist.

Here is my Feeds.py:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from server_status.models import Event
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class LatestEvents(Feed):
    title="List of All Active and Scheduled Events"
    link="/event/"
    description="This RSS feed contains a list of all active and scheduled events."

    def items(self):
        return Event.objects.order_by('-date_active')

    def item_title(self, item):
        return Event.objects.get(event_title='event-title')

    def item_description(self, item):
        return Event.objects.get(event_description='event_descrption')

    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('event', args=[Event.pk])
```

Here is the error that is thrown with local variables:

```
H:\interview\server_status\feeds.py in item_title
        return Event.objects.get(event_title='event-title') ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
item    <Event: Server down for routine maintenance>
self    <server_status.feeds.LatestEvents object at 0x03563230>
```

The event object does exist in the database as I added it myself.  I added it through the admin site if that makes any difference.

And in case there's something up with my model, this is the model which is being accessed:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_status=models.ForeignKey(Status)
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    event_description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_active=models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    time_active=models.TimeField(default=timezone.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_title
```

Comment: The logic in your `item_title` and `item_description` methods doesn't make sense. Those methods are supposed to return a title/description for the `item` object that is passed to the function. Why are you trying to fetch a new object there? Those functions should return a string, not an `Entry` object.

Comment: @solarissmoke So you're suggesting that instead of getting the objects I should return the string representation of the title and description?

Comment: You already *have* an object in that function. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what those methods are for. They take an instance of `Event` and should return strings that represent the title and description of that object. You probably want something along these lines:

```
class LatestEvents(Feed):

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.event_title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.event_description

    def item_link(self, item):
        return reverse('event', args=[item.pk])
```

You should not be using the `Event` class itself anywhere in these methods (other than in `items()`).

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for!  Works now!